# Using Window Function to calculate RMS

Tags: stm32, adc, signal-processing, dma

The code below is from this site: https://community.cypress.com/thread/51426

I'm trying to understand what is happening in that code.

1. Do I really need double type variables? This code is implemented using a PsoC device, but I'm trying to implement it in STM32 Cortex M0+ with 12 bit ADC and no FPU. So I think I can use float32 variables, right?
2. The Hann Function is given by `Hanning = a0 + a1 * Cos (2*PI*i/N); -N/2 <= i <= N/2.` This agrees with Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hann_and_Hamming_windows. But then in the ConfigRMS16 function it says: `double Y = a0 + a1 * cos( M_PI * ((double) i) / ((double) (NO_SAMPLES-1)) );` Is M_PI equivalent to 2*PI?
3. Why is the Window scaled to 8 bit? Is a quad buffer needed? Why not double buffer?
4. I have initialized the ADC and DMA in the STM32 and it works ok. But in order to translate this code to STM32 I need to fully understand it, so any other help is appreciated. I understand this approach is good for signals with discontinuities, that's why I want to use it.

**RMS.c**

```
#include <RMS.h>
#include <math.h>       // sqrt
#include <FastSqrt.h>   // fsqrt(): fast square root calculator 

#define sqrt2 1.4142135623730950488016887242097         //sqrt(2)

static double RMS_TO_V = 1.024 / 32768.0;   // conversion coeff RMS_d (RMS16) to Volts

static uint32 Wght32;                       // Total Gaussian weight (sum of weighting coefficients
static uint8 BufferSection = 0;             // ..0,..1,..2,..3
                    
   
//==============================================================================
// Prepare window function and calculate total weight
// Hanning window:
// Hanning = a0 + a1 * Cos (2*PI*i/N); -N/2 <= i <= N/2
// a0 = 0.5 and a1 = 0.5
//==============================================================================

void ConfigRMS16() 
{
    const double a0 = 0.5;                  // Hanning  (standard deviation (0.3-0.4)E-4)
    const double a1 = 0.5;
    const double scale = 255.0;             //  8-bit window
    uint16 i=0;
    
    Wght32 = 0;                             // Total window weight  
    
    // Hanning 8-bit-> 
    for( i=0; i<NO_SAMPLES; i++ )           // calculate  1/2 window weight
    {
        double Y = a0 + a1 * cos( M_PI * ((double) i) / ((double) (NO_SAMPLES-1)) ); 
        //uint8 Y8 = (uint8) (scale * Y);
        uint8 Y8 = round (scale * Y);       // convert to 8-bit
        Window[i] = Y8;                     // fill weighting function buffer
        Wght32  += Y8;                      // calculate 1/2 window total weight
    }
    Wght32 <<=1;                            // total window weight 
}


//==============================================================================
// Calculate RMS in half-buffer with 16-bit precision 
//==============================================================================

double GetRMS16() 
{
    uint64 AccMS64 = 0;                     // Multiply-Accumulate for mean square
    uint16 offset1=0, offset2=0;            // starting offsets for left and right half of Window
    uint16 i;
    int16 v;
         
    switch (BufferSection)
    {
        case 0: // -->0..1..2--3
                offset1 = 3 * NO_SAMPLES;
                offset2 = 0;
                BufferSection=1;            // next section
                break;
                
        case 1: // --0-->1..2..3
                offset1 = 0;
                offset2 = NO_SAMPLES;
                BufferSection=2;            // next section
                break;
                
        case 2: // ..0--1-->2..3
                offset1 = NO_SAMPLES;
                offset2 = 2 * NO_SAMPLES;
                BufferSection=3;            // next section
                break;
                
        case 3: // ..0..1--2-->3
                offset1 = 2 * NO_SAMPLES;
                offset2 = 3 * NO_SAMPLES;
                BufferSection=0;            // next section
                break;
    
        default:                            // should not come here
                BufferSection=0;                            
    } 
    
    for( i=0; i<NO_SAMPLES; i++) {                          // calculate RMS
        v = Buffer[i+offset1];                              // Buffer data are signed
        AccMS64 +=  (uint64)(v*v) * Window[(NO_SAMPLES-1)-i]; // accumulate 
    }

    for( i=0; i<NO_SAMPLES; i++) {                          // calculate RMS
        v = Buffer[i+offset2];                              // Buffer data are signed
        AccMS64 +=  (uint64)(v*v) * Window[i];              // accumulate
    }
    

    //RMS16 = sqrt( AccMS64 / GWght32 );         // RMS rounded to 16-bit scale //131us/..us (using standard lib)
    RMS16 = fsqrt( AccMS64 / Wght32 );         // RMS rounded to 16-bit scale //106us/68us  (using fast lib)

    RMS_V = (double)RMS16 * RMS_TO_V;           // calculated RMS in Volts //107us
    
    return RMS_V; 
}
```

**RMS.h**

```
Useful formulas for Default settings:
 *  ADC_SamplingRate = 4000
 *  NO_SAMPLES = 200
 *  AC_signal_frequency = 50 Hz
 *
 *  Window_size            = 2 * NO_SAMPLES = 2*200 = 400 samples
 *  Window_size_t          = 2 * NO_SAMPLES / ADC_SampleRate = 2*200 / 4000Hz = 100ms
 *  AC_period              = 1 / AC_signal_frequency = 1 / 50Hz = 20 ms
 *  AC_periods_per_window  = Window_size_t / AC_period = 2*NO_SAMPLES * AC_frequency / ADC_SampleRate = 2*200*50Hz/4000Hz = 5
 *  AC_frequency_min       = ADC_SampleRate / (2*NO_SAMPLES) = 4000Hz / 2*200 = 10Hz
 *  AC_frequency_max       = ADC_SamplingRate / min_ADC_samples_per_AC_period = 4000 / (26.6) = 150 Hz (~1% error)
 *  RMS report frequency   = ADC_SamplingRate / NO_SAMPLES = 4000Hz / 200 = 20 Hz
 *  RMS group delay        = NO_SAMPLES / ADC_SampleRate = 200 / 4000Hz = 50 ms
 *  min_ADC_samples_per_AC_period = ADC_SamplingRate / AC_frequency = 4000Hz / 150 Hz = 26.6 (1% error)
 *  ADC_sample_processing_time = processing_time / NO_SAMPLES = (approx.) 220us (123us release) / 200 = 1.2us/sample (debug), 0.6us (release)
 *  Processing_time        = ADC_sample_processing_time * NO_SAMPLES = 1.1us (0.6us) * 200 = 220us (debug) / 120us (release)
 *  processor load (%)     = 1.1us/sample * NO_SAMPLES * RMS report frequency = 1.1us/sample * ADC_SamplingRate = 0.44% (debug) / 0.24% (release)
 *
 * ========================================================================================================================
*/

#include <project.h>


#define NO_SAMPLES 200u             // number of samples to acquire (1/4 buffer)
//#define NO_SAMPLES 400u           // number of samples to acquire (1/4 buffer)


int16 Buffer[4 * NO_SAMPLES];       // RAM buffer to hold acquired data (signed), double buffered

uint8 Window[NO_SAMPLES];           // RAM buffer holding weighting function coefficients (8-bit)


uint16 RMS16;                       // RMS scaled to 16-bit
double RMS_V;                       // RMS voltage (Volts)
    
//============================================
// Forward declarations
//============================================

void   ConfigRMS16();               // Fill weighting function buffer (16-bit) 
double GetRMS16();                  // returns RMS (Volts)
uint8  RMSV_to_VDAC(double value);  // convert RMSV to VDAC8 code

/* [] END OF FILE */
```

Answer (score 0):

Double is only used for the result, all the  repeated computations are done using fixed point. (that is integer operations), this is why the values are scaled to 8-bit

I have no idea why they are doing a quad buffer, I suspect they are not recomputing after every sample, only periodically. there's too many global variables involved to get a full picture.